# Where to ask about processor design

Tags: discussion

I would like to ask a question about CPU design; I am no sure whether it belongs on this site or not. It is at an architecture level, rather than at the level of transistors and other components.

Where would the appropriate place be to ask a question about CPU design?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into the stacks which Dave had mentioned.  If you find that EE.SE would be a good fit, you're welcome to give it a try.  If it turns out that some other stack is a better fit, we'll benignly migrate your question there.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's both [Computer Science.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) and [Theoretical Computer Science.SE](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: they declared my question off topic

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer Did they say why? Might be helpful in determining whether EE.SE is a better fit.